# What is the best way to cool a vaulted ceiling in a marine tropical environment?

Tags: hvac, insulation, ventilation, cooling

A house I am working on has vaulted ceilings with no insulation or ventilation, so the rooms get very very hot during mid-day to afternoon, especially in the summer. The house has a white standing seam metal roof on top of plywood and exposed rafters.

I would like to add air conditioning, so adding insulation will likely be a necessity, but also have the option to live in a much cooler space without a/c.

The house is located in a very salty tropical marine environment so salt, mold, and hurricanes must be strongly considered in any improvement.

The options look like ventilation, insulation, and a radiant barrier. Dropping the ceiling to the bottom of the rafters and adding insulation in between looks like an easy option.

I imagine ventilation in the newly enclosed ceiling space will be key, but preventing mold in this salty, humid environment will be tricky. Spray foam looks better for mold and humidity, but that takes away the option for a radiant barrier, which may be very effective in this sunny environment.  Also, closed cell spray foam could help strengthen the roof for hurricanes as the rafters are 2x8s spaced at 24".

Also, for days when not using A/C, ventilation could be added high on the wall below the ceiling space to let hot air escape from the room. Does it make sense to have ventilation above and below the ceiling? Is there a type of ventilation system that is safe for hurricanes and can be opened or closed with a/c usage? Will wall insulation make a big difference and are there any other tricks to passively cool this space?

[image: House Interior]

[image: House Exterior]

Comment: Is having a high ceiling a must have?   Dropping the ceiling so the A/C has less space to cool is an idea.  Depending on if costs is possible can add storage space in the new attic.

Comment: It is always good to keep outside temperatures outside, which insulation does a decent job(walls and ceiling).  The inside(under) of the roof deck should be ventilated, usually  by having vents low(bottom of roof) and high(near peak).  Keeping the sun from shining on the windows will help also, awnings or reflective film.

Comment: Anything to stop the sun hitting the walls / roof - aka shading. Trees  are good as they have leaves in summer and loose them in winter, automat6ic as well. Go with the idea that stopping the heat getting in is better than dealing with it after. So control the outside envelope...

Comment: What does the exterior roof look like?

Comment: Hot air rises, cold air falls.  Installing a mini-split system would give conditioned air in the lower areas where you actually live.  It will remove humidity as well.